Find all functions $f : [0,1] \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ satisfying the given conditions.

Let, $m \geq 2$ be an integer. Find all functions $f : [0,1] \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ which are bounded by $2024^{2024}$ and also satisfy $$f(x) = \frac {1} {m^2} \left (f (0) + f \left (\frac {x} {m} \right ) + f \left (\frac {2x} {m} \right ) + \cdots + f \left (\frac {(m-1)x} {m} \right ) \right ).$$

My Attempt $:$ Clearly if $f \equiv 0$ then it satisfies the given conditions. Now let $M = 2024^{2024}$ and $f : [0,1] \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ be any function satisfying the given conditions. Then we first note that $f(0) = 0$ which can be easily obtained from the linear expression of $f(x)$ by putting $x = 0.$ Let us choose $x \in (0,1]$ arbitrarily. Then $$\begin{align*} f(x) & = \frac {1} {m^2} \left (f \left (\frac {x} {m} \right ) + f \left (\frac {2x} {m} \right ) + \cdots + f \left (\frac {(m-1)x} {m} \right ) \right ) \tag{1} \\ & = \frac {1} {m^4} \left ( \left (f \left (\frac {x} {m^2} \right ) + \cdots + f \left (\frac {(m-1)x} {m^2} \right ) \right ) + \left (f \left (\frac {2x} {m^2} \right ) + \cdots + f \left (\frac {2(m-1)x} {m^2} \right ) \right ) + \cdots + \\ + \left (f \left (\frac {(m-1)x} {m^2} \right ) + \cdots + f \left (\frac {(m - 1)^2 x} {m^2} \right ) \right ) \right ) \tag{2} \end{align*}$$
From $(1)$ we have $\left \lvert f(x) \right \rvert \lt \frac {M} {m}$ and from $(2)$ we have $\left \lvert f(x) \right \rvert \lt \frac {M} {m^2}.$ Arguing in a similar manner after $n^{\text{th}}$ iterations we would have $\left \lvert f(x) \right \rvert \lt \frac {M} {m^n}.$ Since $m \geq 2,$ it follows that $m^n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty.$ Thus $\frac {M} {m^n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty,$ and consequently $f(x) = 0.$ Since $x$ were arbitrarily taken it follows that $f \equiv 0.$
Conclusion $:$ There is only one function which satisfies the given conditions; namely the function $f \equiv 0.$
Is it fine what I did? Any suggestion for improvement would be gladly welcomed.
Thanks for reading.
